# iOS Game Player IDs

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, fbconnect, gamekit

I am going to work on a game project for the first time. I have some thoughts in pieces, but couldn't get all things to make sense.

**The Game can only be played if the user is logged in.**
Plan to let user has the following options to login:

1. Game Center ID
2. Facebook ID
3. registered ID (email/username/password) with my server.

Question: does it make sense? Looks like there is no API to get user's Game Center ID, so that I can post it to my server.
For Facebook ID, I can get it and post to server. 
Registered ID surely no programed.

I need those IDs to be posted to server because, I need to keep record in server for a game achievement award system by us, apart from Game Center's Leader Board.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Seems very vague

Comment: It is about what kinds of IDs can I use to get user login my Game App. E.g. Draw Something, they have FBConnect and email, Game center is third option? I am not sure.

Comment: Well Facebook connect is a service provided by Facebook and there are many tutorials on how to integrate that. Your own login you will obviously have to provide yourself.

Comment: thanks for your reply. no problem with codes for using FBConnect. The question is focusing on the big picture.

Comment: Well you are likely to get more help if you focus in on a particular issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a unique player ID for Game Center by `playerID` property of `GKPlayer` class. See [GKPlayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKPlayer/playerID).

Comment: Thanks. Halley. So am I correct that I can identify a Game Player by GMplayer's ID, or FB_ID, or my own server created ID?

Comment: If the formats of the 3 kinds of ID are guaranteed to be different, you are correct. But I am not sure about the "if" :) Be careful since Apple and Facebook are able to change their spec. Maybe you can add a prefix to solve this, like "GK_[GKplayerID]", "FB_[FB_ID]" and "MY_[YOUR_OWN_ID]"?

Comment: There is a flaw in gamecenter authentication, find question I wrote you will know.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong, GameCenter actually does have a playerID API. [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6)

Thanks.